# Android Studio: debug an already running application without restart

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Is it possible in Android Studio to debug an already running application without restarting it (assuming the application was previously installed through Android Studio)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this step (I assume that you have connected device and USB debugging option is turned on):

Step 1 : Click on Attach Debugger option.

[image]

Step 2 : Now dialog is open, select the process you want to run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOu3N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOu3N.png) besides run and debug ones to add debug to your running app. You have to run the debug build to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just click on the button highlighted in the given image

[image: Image from android studio 2.3]

After clicking this image select the process, running on any attached device,  which you want to debug.